# Expectation subscript notation

Tags: probability, statistics

http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture8.pdf At the bottom of page 1 in this pdf, they say the expectation is taken over theta, but I don't understand why the expectation isn't over X when the integration is over x. I thought it might be a mistake but it seems the same everywhere else so it must be correct.

Comment: "they say the expectation is taken over theta" No, they say the expectation is taken with respect to P_theta, which is the probability measure used to compute expectations of functions of X when the parameter is fixed at theta.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but when they have the theta subscript I always thought that means to take the expectation over every possible value of theta